Filter not filtering the frequency of interest
My board failed RE at frequency 500M, 750MHz and 910MHz, which I drilled down to a few BNC connector that could be the suspect. I connect one of the BNC connector to a spectrum analyzer and found many frequency peaks.
This connector is isolated input designed to take in external source for processing.
Unfortunately I am unable to do a major relayout, so I am focusing on preventing the noise from radiating out so I added a few capacitors to my input filter to try and attenuate this range of frequency more.
Here is a snippet of the filter:

I added one 100pF capacitor to the left and right side of the CMC respectively, and ran LTspice simulation. The result show it has 60dB and 76dB of attenuation at frequency 500MHz and 750MHz respectively. But when I kludge the capacitor to the filter, the measurement on my spectrum analyzer show that the 500MHz have gone down 7dB, 910MHz gone down by 6dB but 750MHz have not moved at all.

The Blue trace is the original filter design without capacitor, while green trace is after adding 100pF capacitors to the sides of the CMC.
Any idea what could be the cause of 750MHz not seeing any improvements? One thing I noticed is that when I shorted the metal shell of the BNC to chassis ground, all the noise went down a lot.
Note: The filter is on top layer and I have a solid power plane on L2 and GND plane at L4.

Components and simulations don't mean much at this frequency -- please show layout and photos of the unit and connectors. Have you tested the solution in the lab yet?


Any idea what could be the cause of 750MHz not seeing any
improvements?

I would say that the 750 MHz source of interference isn't coming from where you believe it to be coming from or, is common-mode (rather than differential) or vice versa. In my experience, radiated emission peaks that are problematic usually come from 2 or more places and there is no simple "one port fix". Sure you can target the highest unwanted emitter but, usually, you need to fix another that only appears once the main one is fixed.
